# How to compare two tables on two different servers, in SSIS within one package

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, database, ssis

I need to compare two tables on two different servers.
I need to get rows from two tables (based on the same keys), which exist in the first table but do not exist in the second table(based on binary checksum(hashKey)). After that I need to load them into a stage table.

```
server1.database1.table1.HashKey<>server2.database2.table2.HashKey2
```

I need to receive these rows and insert them to a table.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Add a *connection manager* to both servers in the solution explorer. Then add the two data sources of your desired type(OLE DB, ODBC..)  to your data flow(you can add the connection manager directly in the source editor if you like). Now you should be able to manipulate both tables.

It this what youre looking for?

Take a look at this:

Each of those sources would be a table from their respective servers. It is necessary to sort before you join.

[image: Workflow]

In the *Merge Join* editor you can pick what kind of join it is and on what you would like to join.

After that you can use either  a *Conditional Split* of a *Derived column* transform to filter/manipulate your data befor you create a destination task and load it back into some table.

Comment: This is the basic structure of what I think you're trying to do. If you add more information to que question I will be able to have a better idea of your problem.

Comment: Let me know how it works out and if you have anymore questions. And if this answer initial question please mark as answer.

Comment: Hi again, I didnt have a time for solving this case until today. So I tried this solution but I have a problem with using MERGO JOIN, It doesnt solve my problem. Look, I have a table on one server(its a table with all data which are updated ones for day I think) and I have a another table on another server with records which contains data(list of keys) from that first table, but from previous day. So I need to select records (with same keys) which were changed after todays load and insert them anywhere. Its easy in foundation but I dont want to load all present contain of first table.